# Incorrect syntax near 'PROCEDURE' postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-10

My database is hosted in Amazon and I am using pgAdmin 4 to connect to it.
I copy-pasted snippet from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_data(a integer, b integer)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
   INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (a);
   INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (b);
$$;
```

The issue is that I get 'incorrect syntax near 'PROCEDURE' ' error
[image]

What is done wrong? Not sure how I check version of postgresql itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Postgres 10, you need to use a function:

```
CREATE function insert_data(a integer, b integer)
  returns void
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
   INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (a), (b);
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to PostgreSQL documentation, syntax is supported in versions 11 and 12.

> [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 11: CREATE PROCEDURE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html)
>
> [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/) → [PostgreSQL 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/index.html)
>
> Supported Versions: [Current](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) ([11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html))
>
> Development Versions: [12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createprocedure.html) / [devel](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-createprocedure.html)

Check PostgreSQL version on your server, run this query from PgAdmin:

```sql
SELECT version();
```

Comment: thanks, it is "PostgreSQL 10.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.9.3, 64-bit"
there is no way I create procedure for it?

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo: use a function then