# Syntax error at 'PROCEDURE' on PostgreSQL 11.5 too

Tags: postgresql

In previously question ([Incorrect syntax near 'PROCEDURE' postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706240/incorrect-syntax-near-procedure-postgresql)) have an answare, that "CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE" work only PostgreSQL 11 or later.
I'm have a PostgreSQL **11.5**, but same result occured;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE diag01 ( Mese text)
  language plpgsql as
$A$
begin
  raise info 'Kapta: %', Mese;
end;
$A$;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"

LINE 1: CREATE PROCEDURE diag01 ( Mese text)
               ^
```

Thanks

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a47c59e2578706fd9b49ab590708d548)

Comment: neither do i...

Comment: me neither, works fine. Are you sure about the version? SELECT version();